# How to return false if all numerical values of 0-9 are matching WITH other characters in string?

Tags: php, javascript, html, regex, validation

I am specifically targeting numerical only, So if I am using a phone mask using javascript on front end that filters user input to (000)000-000, basically [2-9] and [0-9] as mask ([jquery.maskedinput-1.3.js](http://code.google.com/p/allios/source/browse/branches/25.07.2011/WebContent/jquery.maskedinput-1.3.js?r=209)) and mobile filter...

```
jQuery(function ($e) {
var isMobile = navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPhone|iPod|iPad|Android|BlackBerry)/);
$e('#refer').val(window.location.href);

if (!(isMobile)) {      
    $e('#phone').mask('(299)299-9999');
    $e('#field_phone_number').mask('299-299-9999');
}
});
```

For server side I have a regular expression in PHP as (nothing special yet)

```
function phonenumber($value)
{
    return preg_match("/\(?\b[(. ]?[0-9]{3}\)?[). ]?[0-9]{3}[-. ]?[0-9]{4}\b/i", $value);
}
```

How can a create a regex or php script that targets all numerical values without creating a very long regex for each character? I just want to know if someone types in (222)222-2222, they get a false on the return.

Comment: You could remove all not digit characters and then compare to strings like `2222222222` insteadt of comparing to `(222)222-2222`.

Comment: Sorry, but I did not understand. The regex must recognize (XXX)XXX-XXXX, where X is between 0 and 9?

Comment: @clentfort we want to save the characters as is, this validation returns false and user has chance to correct if they submit incorrect. So I don't want to strip, then replace.

Comment: You don't have to destroy the input, copy it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function phonenumber($value)
{
    $prefix = '\d{3}'; // You might want to specify '2\d\d' (200 to 299)
    $regex = '#^(\('.$prefix.'\)|'.$prefix.')[\s\.-]?\d{3}[\.-]?\d{4}$#';
    if (preg_match($regex, $value))
    {
        // Number is in a suitable format

        // Now extract digits -- remove this section to not test repeated pattern
        $digits = preg_replace('#[^\d]+#', '', $value);

        // All numbers equal are rejected
        if (preg_match('#^(\d)\1{9}$#', $digits))
            return false;
        // end of pattern check

        // Otherwise it is accepted
        return true;
    }
    return false; // Not in a recognized format
}
```

This will accept (299)423-1234 and 277-111-2222, and also (400)1234567 or 4001234567. It will reject (400-1234567 and 400-12-34-56-7. It will also reject (222)222-2222 because of the repeated 2's.

Comment: Awesome, that worked like a charm! Btw, I changed your $phone to $value in the digit extractor.

Comment: Thank you. I had seen your `$value` too late, and changed *only the first instance* of my own `$phone`, forgetting the second. Sorry if I seemed dense, but I'm not familiar with US (?) phone format. I guess 2xx is a cellular prefix?

Comment: for example here the 2's (2XX)2XX-XXXX in our format will never be valid if a 0 or a 1, but the others can hold 0-9, so just a way I figured good to eliminate bad numbers. We could build a database or list to get more specific but then it is overboard. This is for all phone numbers in the US, not just cellular.

Comment: Update: I ended up adding `$prefix = '[2-9]{1}\d{1}\d{1}';` to get the proper 200-299 filter. '2\d\d' would not work for me.

Comment: Oh, then you can use `[2-9]\d\d` -- `{1}` is the default, you can omit it. Or `[2-9]\d{2}`, but I think `[2-9]\d\d` is clearer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a backreference `\1` to detect recurring patterns. In your case you can simply mix in a `.*` to ignore in-between fillers like `(` and `-`

```
  /(\d)(.*\1){7}/
```

Will look for a number, and at least 7 repetitions of the same, ignoring any other characters used as filler. This will not ensure that they are consecutive however, so `(222)222-8222` would match too.

Comment: How would you impliment this into my preg_match()? I am getting an invalid on all formatting I try while testing.